# Late 90s movie with kids in a strange house, cake burns hole in the floor, trap doors, fake walls, etc

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm asking on behalf of my wife who has remembered seeing this movie for a long time. Here are the key details she remembers about the movie:

- It was seen on TV around 1997 or before.
- It involves a boy, a girl, and a baby who are dropped off at an older male relative's house.
- The setting looked to be about 90s based on cars.
- The house seemed abandoned when the kids arrived.
- Weird things started happening when the kids got inside: trap doors, fake walls, etc.

Remembered scenes:

- At some point, the kids got separated and the boy was looking for the girl and the baby. He went into a room where he could see the girl in a rocking chair with the baby, but when he walked up to her she was holding a snake and she started laughing like an insane person. He ran out of the room.
- Later, the kids had found each other and entered a room with a large cake. The boy went to eat the cake, and the girl slapped the spoon out of his hand. When the cake hit the floor it burnt a hole in the floor. Then, you could see the older relative coming up through the floor laughing.
- The kids tried to run outside, but the world had changed and everything had reverted to Western times with a ghost town and abandoned wagons.

My wife is aware of the resemblance of the main characters to the characters from *A Series of Unfortunate Events*, but she doesn't think it is connected. At the very least, she is certain it was a movie and she doesn't think her dates could be off by more than a few years--so it couldn't have been seen later than about 2001.

Comment: There was [a movie version of A Series of Unfortunate Events](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0339291/) back in 2004, but even so the remembered scenes your wife describes don't seem to line up with what I remember of it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is actually [The Tale of the Whispering Walls](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0514450/), an episode of *Are You Afraid of the Dark?* from 1993.

> After a day in the park, babysitter Louise and two pre-teenagers get lost in the highway and stop at a mansion where things aren't what they seem.

It's all there. The kids come across:

- The young babysitter sitting in a rocking chair with a swaddled baby which turns out to be a huge snake;
- A table with some desserts, and when the boy tries to eat the banana split, the sister knocks it over with a spoon and it burns a hole through the floor;
- And an inn from the past with people in old-timey clothes.

It's currently on Yotube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e1SWI7botOk).

Comment: My wife is freaking out. That's definitely it! Thanks for hunting this down!